# Spark over Yarn - Incorrect Application Master selection

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to fire some jobs with Spark over Yarn with the following command (this is just an example, actually i'm using different amount of memory and core) :

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.mypack.myapp \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --num-executors 3 \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    lib/myapp.jar \
```

When I look at the Web UI to see what's is really happening under the hood, I notice that YARN is picking as Application Master a node that is not the Spark Master. This is a problem because the real Spark Master node is forcefully  involved into the distributed computation leading to unnecessary network transfers of data (because, of course, the Spark master has no data to start with).

For what I saw during my tests, Yarn is picking the AM in a totally random fashion and I can't find a way to force him picking the Spark Master as AM.

My cluster is made of 4 nodes (3 Spark slaves, 1 Spark Master) with 64GB of total RAM and 32 cores, built upon HDP 2.4 with HortonWorks. The Spark Master is only hosting the namenode, the three slaves are datanodes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to specify a node, which does not have any DataNodes, to run the Spark Master. This, as far as I know, is not possible out of the box.

What you could do is run the master in yarn-client mode on the node which is running the NameNode, but this is probably not what you are looking for.

Another way would be to create your own Spark Client (where you specify using YARN API to prefer certain nodes over others for your Spark Master).